# Virtual box NAT , HOST-ONLY and INTERNAL NETWORK

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, virtualbox, nat

When configured the NAT only then able to browse internet in the guest.
But when "adapter 2" setting is enabled and configured with the 'Host Only Network' and "adapter 3" setting is configured with 'internal', then not able to access internet from guest. So what are the sections I need to check to establish the internet connection from guest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When set it up for the first time it was working correctly but after restart of the machine I am facing this problem

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean guest instead of host? None of these adapter settings should affect the host's ability to connect to the internet. Also, there is no "internet  only" network adapter setting. Do you mean the adapter is set to "internal"? Please clarify and add more detail by editing your post. As it stands now it is not clear exactly what is your current setup.

Comment: @n8te  Thanks for mentioning the errors. I edited the question

Comment: For internal and host-only the guest does not have access to the internet. See this table [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#idm2931) in the virtualbox documentation. It details what has access to what for the different virtualbox network adapter options.

Comment: But I have NAT there in "adapter 1" setting. With that same setting I was able to do the internet browse but NAT+HOST ONLY+INTERNEL creating problem after restart. Before restart when I created this three combination for the first time, I was able to connect to the internet.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought you meant you were switching between each option. Didn't realize you had all three simultaneously.

Comment: Any solution or hints which can help to resolve this problem.

Comment: The NAT setting allows you to connect to the internet. So you had that set and everything was fine. You added the next two and were only able to still connect at that time because the additional two network adapters you added didn't really take effect, so to speak, until after you rebooted. Is there any reason you need 3 different types of network adapters configured simultaneously?

Comment: I can't imagine what situation would require NAT and host-only at the same time. NAT in some ways acts as host-only in regards to other devices on your network, but at the same time you are at least able to get out to the internet on the guest. At most I could see you needing Internal + NAT if you want the guest to get out to the internet but also want the VMs to be able to reach each other.

Comment: Yes, actually I am configuring a two node RAC environment. So There will be two guest. So internal adapter setting is created, Actually I was blindly following one document for the network setup. I think I need to change the netwrok setting like NAT+INTERNAL+INTERNAL not like NAT+HOST+INTERNAL. Thanks n8te to raise a logical question.

Comment: You might look into just a single "NAT Network" adapter (as opposed to the regular NAT adapter) on each VM. The NAT Network adapter basically is a combination of NAT + Internal in one adapter. The VMs are NAT'd on their own separate network and can reach each other.